# Difference between StandardOpenOption.WRITE + StandardOpenOption.CREATE with/without TRUNCATE_EXISTING?

Tags: java, file, nio, java-io

Probably a simple answer but I've tried reading the javadoc documentation on StandardOpenOption but I'm still unclear of what happens when I say

`Files.write(..., ..., StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE); // Write A`

Based on some local tests, it looks like this will still overwrite the file if it exists already, so what is the difference between the above and

`Files.write(..., ..., StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.CREATE); // Write B`?

Furthermore, I have a program with two threads that read/write from the written file. When I use Write B, I sometimes get a race condition where one thread would've created the file, and the other overwrites it while the first thread is reading and I get an exception. But when I use Write A, I never get this race condition. Almost as if it'll lock the file first? Can someone explain what is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 6):

when you use the [`StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html#TRUNCATE_EXISTING) the length of the file is first "truncated to 0" if the file already exist **before** any writing:

```
$ jshell

jshell> import java.nio.file.*;

jshell> Path path = Paths.get("foo");
path ==> foo

jshell> Files.write(path, "AAAA".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
```

I've just create a new file named "foo" containing the string "AAAA":

```
$ more foo
AAAA
$
```

now I write the string "BB" to the file **without** `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING` option:

```
jshell> Files.write(path, "BB".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)
```

and just the first two characters gets overwritten, the others are still there:

```
$ more foo
BBAA
$
```

now I write the string "BB" again but I **add** `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING` option:

```
jshell> Files.write(path, "BB".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING)
```

the file contains just "BB" because its previous content has been "erased" by `StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING` before the writing:

```
$ more foo
BB
$
```